# How should a pure function read a config file or open a database?

Tags: javascript, typescript, computer-science

Often I have functions that need data from either a config file or a database. I would prefer pure functions at much as possible and something that can be unit tested.

I have no idea how to do this correctly, as I don't have a CS degree. The options I can see are:

**Example 1:**

```
function myFunc(p1, p2, db, configFile) { ... }
```

but that means all other functions that calls `myFunc()` also needs to have `db, configFile` as arguments.

**Example 2:**

```
function myFunc(p1, p2) { 
  const config = readConfig();
  dbConn = openDb();    
  ...
}
```

I suppose this make unit testing impossible?

**Example 3:**

```
const struct = {
  config: readConfig(),
  dbConn: openDb(),
  ...
};

function myFunc(p1, p2, struct) { ... }
```

This have the down side, that when other functions data also gets stored in this global `struct` then each function have access to more than what they need.

**Question**

Are there other possibilities? What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Dependency Injection here. Something like this:

```js
function readConfig() { 
 // returns real config
}
function openDb() {
 // return real db connection
}
function readConfigMock() { 
 // returns mock config
}
function openDbMock() {
 // return mock db connection
}
function myFuncBuilder(readConfigFn, openDbFn) { 
  return function(p1, p2) {
      // can use readConfigFn everywhere because of closure
      const config = readConfigFn();
      dbConn = openDbFn();    
      ...
  }
}
const myFunc = myFuncBuilder(readConfig, openDb);

// no need to know about openDb and readConfig
function topFunc() {
  myFunc(p1, p2);
}

// code
const myFunc = myFuncBuilder(readConfig, openDb);

// test
const myFunc = myFuncBuilder(readConfigMock, openDbMock);
```

The trick is passing a function as an argument. Also, there is higher-order function (function that returns function) called `myFuncBuilder`. This function builds `myFunc` based on 2 arguments - function for db connection and function for config.

So you can easily create a mocks of `readConfig` and `openDb` for testing.

P.S. Also, Functional Programming paradygm teaches us to use IO monads in such cases. But using monads in JS/TS has a really steep learning curve.

Comment: I can't make it work. Here is my attempt. https://jsfiddle.net/6387mcw4/1/

Comment: I'd updated my answer. Your `readConfig` and `openDb` should be declared at top level, not in `myFunc` body. Also, `myFunc` should take 2 additional arguments (functions)

Comment: I have modified your code to an working example at https://jsfiddle.net/8qc5a19w/1/ . But I don't understand the befit of this, as I still have to pass in `readConfig, openDb` in both cases, which is the same as Example 1?

Comment: OK, I see. I'd updated my answer, added Higher-Order function called `myFuncBuilder` that can incapsulate "dirty" funcitons into closure, and return 2-arguments-taking `myFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

Define `myFunc()` like so to keep it pure:

```
function myFunc(p1, p2, readConfig, openDb) { ... }
```

and call it in an enclosed scope

```
// other code here

{
  const config = readConfig();
  const dbConn = openDb();
  myFunc(p1, p2, readConfig, openDb);
}

// other code here
// config and dbConn isn't available here
```

A PoC:

```js
function func(a, b) {
   console.log(a);
   console.log(b);
}

const a = undefined;
const b = undefined;

{
   const a = 'private1';
   const b = 'private2';
   func(a, b);
}

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```